# Retrieve group of varbinary images in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, binary

I have images stored in a `varbinary` column in my database in ASP.NET MVC. I tried to retrieve them using a foreach loop.

I have written content in controller like this

```
    {
        db = new VideoContext();
        ViewData["VideoMenu"] = db.VideosMaster.ToList();
    }
```

and try to display it in view like this:

```
foreach (var v in (IEnumerable<VideoJug.Models.VideosMaster>)ViewData["VideoMenu"])
{
    <img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",    
    Convert.ToBase64String(v.VideoThumbnail));" width="100" height="100" />
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

> Value cannot be null.Parameter name: inArray

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because VideoThumbnail is null for one of the objects in the IEnumerable you're iterating through. You should have a check for that in your loop, and render a default image if that's the case.

```
foreach (var v in (IEnumerable<VideoJug.Models.VideosMaster>)ViewData["VideoMenu"])
{
    if(v.VideoThumbnail != null)
    {
        <img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",    
            Convert.ToBase64String(v.VideoThumbnail));" width="100" height="100" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/video-placeholder.jpg")" width="100" height="100" />
    }
}
```

By the way, rendering an image this way is bad practice. The best way for you to do what you want to do in MVC is to create a separate action in your controller that returns the binary content of your image and render just the URL in that view.

```
// Controller
public ActionResult VideoThumbnail(int videoId)
{
    var video = db.VideosMaster.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == videoId);

    if(video != null && video.VideoThumbnail != null)
    {
        return File(video.VideoThumbnail, "image/jpg");
    }

    return File(Url.Content("~/Content/images/video-placeholder.jpg"), 
            "image/jpg");
}

// View
foreach (var v in (IEnumerable<VideoJug.Models.VideosMaster>)ViewData["VideoMenu"])
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("VideoThumbnail", new { videoId = v.Id })"
        width="100" height="100" />
}
```

Comment: Yes,but still only one image(imageid=1) is displaying looping number of times..instead of all other images